# Why the nodejs heap out of memory for creating Excel file with big data?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, excel, exceljs

I am creating an excel file at nodejs end and returning base64 data to reactJS to download the file. At nodejs end, I am using promise all and fetch data from a server in chunks and append data into Excel as

```
worksheet.addRows(data);
```

For data around 20-30k, it is working fine but for data like 100k, it shows me an error heap out of memory at nodejs end.

I have increase memory allocate to nodejs also but same error

> node --max_old_space_size=5000  app.js

What I am doing wrong any suggestions?

Nodejs

```
const axios = require('axios');
var excel = require("exceljs");

const workbook = new excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");
worksheet.columns = [
  { header: "TicketId", key: "ticketId" },
  { header: "Email", key: 'user_email' },
  { header: "User",  key : 'user_name' },
  { header: "Subject", key: "subject" },
  ...//many more headers
];


exports.getTicketData = async (req, res, next) => {
  
  res.connection.setTimeout(0);

  const { body } = req;
  const token =  body.token;
  const organization_id = body.organization_id;
  const server = body.server;
  const sideFilter = body.sideFilter;

  let baseurl = 'url for server end to fetch data';


  if (baseurl) {
    let data = new Array();
    let limit = 3000;
    const promises = [];

    try {
      let count = await getCount(token,limit, organization_id, baseurl, sideFilter);
      for(var i = 1;i<=count;i++) {
        promises.push(getData(i,limit,organization_id,token, baseurl, sideFilter));
      }


      await Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
      
      }).catch((e) => {
        throw e;
      });
      
      var base64File = await writeExcelAndUpload(workbook);
      return res.status(200).json({ file:base64File });  
    
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ type:'error', msg:'File not generated please contact support staff' });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(400).json({ type:'error', msg:'please define server name' });   
  }

};

let getData = (page,limit, organization_id,token, baseurl, sideFilter) =>{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    axios.post(baseurl+`/v2/get-export`, {
      page:page,
      organization_id:organization_id,
      per_page:limit,
      filter: "",
      sorted:"",
      ...sideFilter
    },{ headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`} }).then(function (response) {
      let dataTemp = response.data.data.data.map((t,i)=>{
        return {
          ...t, 
          name:t.name,
          ...//many more columns like 70
        }
      });
      worksheet.addRows(dataTemp);
      resolve(true); 
    }).catch(function (error) {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}


let getCount =  (token,limit, organization_id, baseurl, sideFilter) => {
  // run an api and return count against limit
}

let writeExcelAndUpload = async (workbook) => {
  const fileBuffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
  let base64File = Buffer.from(fileBuffer).toString('base64');
  base64File = 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,'+base64File;
  return base64File;
}
```

Client side reactjs

```
exportLink = () => {

  postData ={
    ...
  };
  return axios.post(`${baseurl}/api/ticketing/get-ticket`, postData).then(function (response) {

    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = "export.xlsx";
    downloadLink.href = response.data.file;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();

  }).catch(function(error){
    throw error;
  }); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is kinda expected that you may get a heap out of memory when working with such an amount of entries like 100k.

I could suggest you start using pagination, and instead of fetching e.g. 100k of entries at once fetch 1k of entries do what you need with them, then fetch the next 1k of entries repeat until you processed all entries.

Comment: I am doing the same please see the code I am sending the call to fetch data about 3k and on response I am appending that 3k data to workbook

Comment: You should somehow offload the workbook from your heap. e.g. save it to the file, and then use append file or something like this to add new entries if that possible

Comment: save it to the file, and then use append but same issue